# Using Numpy Where on 2 2-d arrays

Tags: python, numpy, where-clause

I am trying this code, but I am having a problem in this Numpy Where section:

```
import numpy as N
....
....
sfolat = N.ravel(N.where((lat>37.5689) & (lat<37.6689)))
sfolon = N.ravel(N.where((lon>-122.4250) & (lon<-122.3250)))
sfocoord = N.ravel(N.where((lat>37.5189) & (lat<37.7189)&(lon>-122.4750) & (lon<-122.2750)))
```

sfocoord returns

```
>>>sfocoord
array([204, 204, 205, 205, 145, 146, 145, 146])
```

Both lat and lon are dimensioned (428,614). I am trying to find locations at/around 37.6189,-122.3750
I would like input of what to change, so the code will work.

Comment: you should edit your answer to do `import numpy as np`, as that is the standard syntax and will improve readability for others

Comment: I prefer using N instead of np

Comment: are all 3 methods returning empty arrays?

Comment: Show what you want and what you get. Use a small data test set that reproduces your problem. Also, describe your problem in more detail. Show a traceback if you get an error.

Comment: Currently, what you are doing with the `np.where` method is to return the indices where has lat > 37.5689 and lat<37.6689, if you do not have any indices that fulfill such a criteria an empty array will be returned,

Comment: Only the last one is giving me an empty array but I am having trouble matching up the lat and lon that work perfectly for the area I am looking at. I want to find what x and y amongst the lat(x,y) and lon(x,y) is the area.

Comment: Okay Now I got some of it @mike and it is giving me array([204, 204, 205, 205, 145, 146, 145, 146]) but when I try lat(204) it is giving me an error.

Comment: That's because you lat is a 2-D matrix matrix. Why are you using ravel?

Comment: I am trying to find which x and y in my lat is the point 37.6189,-122.3750 or at least near that spot

Comment: Add this information to your question and include the traceback. Give the people who want to answer the chance to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`numpy.where` will return a length 2 tuple where the 2 elements are: an array of indices for the rows and an array of the corresponding indices for the columns that satisfied the condition.

`numpy.ravel` will flatten the tuple of the 2 arrays into a single array and you will no longer have 2 distinct arrays for the row and column indices.

To preserve the indices:

```
idx = numpy.where((lat>37.5689) & (lat<37.6689)&(lon>-122.4250) & (lon<-122.3250))
```

Based on your given output for `sfocoord`, your code will likely output,

```
>>>idx 
(array([204, 204, 205, 205]), array([145, 146, 145, 146]))
```

`[204, 204, 205, 205]` are the row indices and `[145, 146, 145, 146]` are the corresponding column indices were the conditions where satisfied.

To get the values from the lat array, using these indices, you can do:

```
lat[idx[0], idx[1]]
```

EDIT: A way for one to see the indices as row, column pairs:

```
>>>numpy.transpose(idx)
array([[204, 145],
   [204, 146],
   [205, 145],
   [205, 146]])
```